# RPi HDMI to RCA

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, composite-video, cable

I live in India and intend to buy a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B sometime soon but do not have a display with a HDMI input. So I'm stuck with RCA (3pin Yellow/White/Red) and S-video (No VGA). I also cannot source any 4 pole 3.5mm to RCA cables where I live and since the cable compatibility is so limited, I'm skeptical about wasting cash on dozens of cables until I find one that works. So for now, I have to make do with some sort of analogue converter for the RPi's HDMI output. I have scoured ebay and found this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Composite-1080P-HDMI-to-RCA-Audio-Video-AV-CVBS-Adapter-Converter-For-HDTV-G-/321638446790?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ae32536c6

My question is whether this box that costs...25% of the RPi's cost will actually do what I need it to do. Will it just be connecting the HDMI from the Pi and the RCA to my TV? I read a review deep in the "Seller's reviews" section where someone said their Chromecast worked with it. Any idea?

Also, I found this on Amazon India: http://www.amazon.in/Etekcity-Composite-Video-Audio-Converter/dp/B008FO7PQA

It seems to be the same as the ebay one w/ branding for 6x the price...

Help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: An adapter for the analog output is going to be vastly simpler and cheaper than an outboard converter from the digital HDMI to an analog signal.  If you really can't source a cable with the right connectors, perhaps you can carefully solder the end of a coaxial cable to the bottom of the board at the jack contacts, if they are through-hole.

Answer (score 3):

For a model B+ or later (which includes the RPi 2), RCA composite video should be achieved through the *3.5mm port* not the HDMI port.

After a quick bit of research, I found two suitable products.

The first is a 3.5mm to RCA converter. It costs US$2.23, but would require a separate RCA male to male cable to connect the Pi to the TV. However, since this is one of the only options available on your TV, you probably already have one. You can buy the converter from ebay **[here.](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/380747364232?clk_rvr_id=713556628784)**

Otherwise, you can use a 3.5mm to RCA *cable*. It costs more, at US$6.36, however you do not need a separate cable to connect it to the TV. You can buy it **[here.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004UCU72U)**

I hope one of these options will work.

Answer (score 1):

I recently purchased Rpi 2 (Me too in India) faced same problem and RCA cable which i got wasn't compatable so cut the cable at middle and soldered as it should work,I used a multimeter to check pins Solder the GND wire to GND 3 seperate connectors together and solder it to corresponding wire which leads to 3rd contact from the tip.

Another solution is to directly solder into test pads on back side of PCB.

[image]

Comment: Sounds legit, I ended up getting a Chromecast but am getting an RPi very soon. I'll resolder if things don't go properly